# Strange URL parameter added on login

Tags: url, login, sessions

I'm seeing an issue where I login on the frontend and the URL becomes `S=c3992270d168f3ec9ab1df5bc06afce3/test` where `test` is the segment I'm passing from the return parameter.

I can't fathom where the first part is coming from though.

Logic in the template is pretty simple

```
{if logged_in}
hello steven
<a href="{path='logout'}">Log Out</a>
{if:else}
{exp:member:login_form return="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}"}
  <p>
    <label>Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="32" size="25">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="32" size="25">
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
  <p><a href="{path='member/forgot_password'}">Forgot your password?</a></p>
{/exp:member:login_form}
{/if}
```

Session related? Structure bug (seen that before) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$config['website_session_type'] = 'c';` has sorted the logic.

Comment: To clarify issue and solution: S stands for session - this is the Session ID in the query string. The config you've changed turns off Session tracking and instead uses Cookies (hence no longer in the URL). There are 2 settings directly related to this: cp-session-type https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#cp-session-type and website-session-type https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#website-session-type